# Docker hub image upload corruption via git action

Tags: git, docker, dockerhub

I'm building LLM through Fast API.

I linked git and git action because I wanted to simplify the cumbersome procedures related to system maintenance.

So, when I push to the main branch of git, I automatically update the image to the docker hub through git action.

However, there is a problem. I download the image from Docker hub for actual deployment after all the processes are finished and start container, the file for embedding starts damaged. And I mean the error as below

```
safetensors_rust.SafetensorError: Error while deserializing header: HeaderTooLarge
```

It was confirmed that the above error comes out when the file is damaged.

Does anyone know how to solve a problem related to this?

To solve this problem, I checked the file for abnormalities through the git clone before the git action was executed, but it worked well. All problems occur in images uploaded to the docker hub after the git action.

Also, it works well when docker push through CMD command without git action.